# Help with page navigation on multipage list

Tags: 2010, list-view

I have a large list of items and have set the view to return 100 items per page.  Is there a way to show the page navigation i.e. "101-200" at the top of each page?  I know the page navigation is at the bottom, but it would be helpful to also show it at the top of each page.  I have tried to search for this answer but am afraid I am not using the correct terms as my search results do not speak to this specific issue.  Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this for?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 2):

Generally in SharePoint 2010 list view is customized via XSLT based approach. 
Since `pagingButtons` template is used for rendering pager, below is demonstrated how customize list view to render an additional pager on top of list view.

**Steps**

1)Create a *custom* list view template and save it as  `ViewWithPagingButtonsonTop.xsl` file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
  version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt x d asp __designer SharePoint ddwrt2"
  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
  xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20"
  xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
  xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
  <xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template name="ViewWithPagingButtonsOnTop" mode="RootTemplate" match="View" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root">
    <xsl:call-template name="pagingButtons" /> <!-- render pager on top -->
    <xsl:call-template name="View_Default_RootTemplate"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> The custom template is intended for rendering pager on top of list
>   view

2)Upload the specified file into `Style Library` under `XSL Style Sheets` folder

3)Open the page where list view resides in `Edit` mode and specify `/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ViewWithPagingButtonsonTop.xsl` value for `XSL Link` property of XLV web part as shown below[image]

4)Save changes

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0e9a698b-dcd0-4d97-941e-52332a524525/how-can-you-move-the-paging-nextprevious-buttons?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy) question has an answer to that with an edit to the AllItems.aspx page moving the ms-paging element around in the XSLT.

> Open you site in designer and go to list folder. Select the
>   particular list and check out the AllItems.aspx page.
>
> Right Click on list design and click "Convert to XSLT view". Just find
>   below tag